# Why is my app running correctly on emulator but fails on phone?

Tags: android

I have developed the application which gives a BroadcastReceiver message.

The code is

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TAG = "Receiver Tutorial";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null && Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Screen is turned ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The app is running correctly in emulator and giving the Toast notification.
But when I am trying to run it on my mobile phone it does not give any toast notification.
I am using a Galaxy Y Duos mobile phone.
I am not able to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The BroadcastReceiver is killed before the toast can be displayed. Since the receiver's process dies, the toast will never show up. To make a toast show up, you will need to start a `Service` to ensure there will still be an app to make the toast once the BroadcastReceiver's code is finished.

Check out the section labeled "Receiver Lifecycle" in the [BroadcastReceiver JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: Can you explain a little further if you have time ?